# socket.io - both private and public messages

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have some trouble how I should structure my application.

It's possible to be in a room with 50+ users, and it's also possible to message a user privately.

Should I have two different emits on the client side? Or should I only have one and let the server decided if it should be a private or public message based on the data (I'm thinking something like a parameter that has true or false)?

Comment: It's just a design choice of yours.  Either way, the server is deciding what to do with the message and who to send it to.  Personally, I'd probably use a separate message name for private messages just because I think the code would be clearer on both client and server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really just a software design choice.  There is no "right" or "wrong" answer.  It's pretty much exactly the same issue as deciding whether you make two functions with separate names for two related pieces of functionality or whether you make one function that you pass different arguments to.

My personal opinion is that your code would be more simpler if you used a separate message name for private messages like this:

```
// send to a single user
socket.emit("privateMessage", {userID: xxxx, msg: "Hello"});

// broadcast to all users in my room
socket.emit("publicMessage", {msg: "Hello"});
```

And, then on the server, you'd have a separate handler for public messages and private messages which is probably a good thing.

Instead of using a common message with arguments:

```
// send to a single user
socket.emit("message", {type: "private", userID: xxxx, msg: "Hello"});

// broadcast to all users in my room
socket.emit("message", {type: "public", msg: "Hello"});
```

Comment: Yeah, I feel most comfortable with this approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

to further clarify jfriend00s answer you need to direct private messages to a specific socket.id.

on server side to send to a specific user:

```
socket.to(<socketid>).emit('message', {type:"private", msg:"Content"});
```

on server side to send to specific room:

```
socket.to('FunRoom').emit('message', {type:"public", msg:"Content"});
```

using:

```
socket.emit("message", {type: "private", userID: xxxx, msg: "Hello"});
```

as suggested would send to the entire room but only show to the specific user using client side code. The private messages could be read from developer tools.

One easy way to do this is with redis:
on the socket connection save the socket.id to the username.

```
redis.set('userID', socket.id);
```

then when a message comes in:

```
socket.on('message', function (message,callback) {
    if(message.type == 'private'){
        redis.get(message.userID, function(err, socketID) {
            if(err){
                return callback(err);//error callback, user may no long be online
            }
            socket.to(socketID).emit('message', message);
            return callback('success')
        });
    }
    socket.to('FunRoom').emit('message', message);
    return callback('success')
}
```

If you take this approach make sure to clean up redis on disconnects:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    redis.del(userID)
    socket.to('FunRoom').emit('userLeft', {userID: userID});
});
```

Even though its late I just wanted to add this as the approach suggested by jfriend00 seemed to suggest leaving the private message filtering up to the client side.